# Python 3.7 bytecode MAKE_FUNCTION: How to interpret such disassembled function declaration?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is my code:

```
x=100
def foo(m, n=66):
    return m + n  

b=200
a=foo(x) + b
print(a)
```

Here is the disassembled:

```
$ python3 -m dis test_func.py
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (100)
              2 STORE_NAME               0 (x)

  2           4 LOAD_CONST               6 ((66,))
              6 LOAD_CONST               2 (<code object foo at 0x7f2c7dba39c0, file "test_func.py", line 2>)
              8 LOAD_CONST               3 ('foo')
             10 MAKE_FUNCTION            1
             12 STORE_NAME               1 (foo)

  5          14 LOAD_CONST               4 (200)
             16 STORE_NAME               2 (b)

  6          18 LOAD_NAME                1 (foo)
             20 LOAD_NAME                0 (x)
             22 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             24 LOAD_NAME                2 (b)
             26 BINARY_ADD
             28 STORE_NAME               3 (a)

  7          30 LOAD_NAME                4 (print)
             32 LOAD_NAME                3 (a)
             34 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             36 POP_TOP
             38 LOAD_CONST               5 (None)
             40 RETURN_VALUE
```

My question is around this part:

```
  2           4 LOAD_CONST               6 ((66,))
              6 LOAD_CONST               2 (<code object foo at 0x7f2c7dba39c0, file "test_func.py", line 2>)
              8 LOAD_CONST               3 ('foo')
             10 MAKE_FUNCTION            1
```

Here is the snippet from the [document](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html) about MAKE_FUNCTION:

```
MAKE_FUNCTION(argc)
Pushes a new function object on the stack. From bottom to top, the consumed stack must consist of values if the argument carries a specified flag value:

0x01   a tuple of default values for positional-only and positional-or-keyword parameters in positional order
0x02   a dictionary of keyword-only parameters’ default values
0x04   an annotation dictionary
0x08   a tuple containing cells for free variables, making a closure
the code associated with the function (at TOS1)
the qualified name of the function (at TOS)
```

I have a hard time interpreting the flags: I do not see any flag in the disassembly.

So let's correlate the disassembly with the doc, when it runs to MAKE_FUNCTION, the stack depth is 3:

```
1. the top is "foo" which comes from instruction @8
2. the next one is code object which comes from instruction @6
3. the bottom one is 66 which comes from instruction @4
```

Now my question is, where in this bytecode is the "flag"? I mean 0x01, 0x02, 0x04 and/or 0x08 mentioned in the doc. Is that "6" in instruction @4? But 6 is 2 and 4 while here it is only positional parameters......

Please help out.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The flag is the argument to the `MAKE_FUNCTION` instruction:

```
         10 MAKE_FUNCTION            1
```

The flag is `1`, which is `0x01`.